# SQL Server function not providing expected result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I have created a SQL Server function to return results based on two filter conditions. In TVF function I just have one select query where the results will be returned in table format. When I run the select query expected results were returned but when I run the same query through function then results are incorrect. Please advise as what is happening in SQL for TVF.

Function is not returning the expected results when we pass more values in parameters.

Sample table data:

```
answer_tag  answer_text
-----------------------
TNBPDS1         250
TSMMBPDS        100
```

My code:

```
Create function [dbo].[OBSLookupByAnswerTextTagX]
     (@pObsId int, 
      @pObsSeq tinyint, 
      @pAnswerTag varchar(10))
return @ReturnTable table 
                    (
                        id int identity(1,1),
                        answer_text varchar(max),
                        answer_tag varchar(max)
                    ) 
begin
    Insert into @ReturnTable (answer_text, answer_tag)
       select distinct ansr.answer_text, ansr.answer_tag 
       from grp_bu_bs gbus
       inner join benefit_summary bsum on (gbus.summary_id = bsum.summary_id)
       inner join answer ansr on (gbus.summary_id = ansr.summary_id)
       where 
           gbus.grp_prod_id = @pObsId
           and gbus.grp_prod_seq = @pObsSeq
           and @pAnswerTag like '%' + (ansr.answer_tag) + '%'

   return
end
```

Below select query from function which gives expected result when we run the query as separate `SELECT` statement.

```
select distinct ANSR.answer_text,ANSR.answer_tag
from grp_bu_bs GBUS
inner join benefit_summary BSUM on (GBUS.summary_id = BSUM.summary_id)
inner join answer ANSR on (GBUS.summary_id = ANSR.summary_id)
where 
    GBUS.grp_prod_id = '189523'
    and GBUS.grp_prod_seq = '31'
    and 'TNBPDS1,TSMMBPDS,TNBPDS12,TNBPDSL3,TNBPDSD,TNBPDSAL' like '%' + ANSR.answer_tag) + '%'
```

If we have tag `'TNBPDS1'` then `250` should be returned.

If we pass parameter as `'TNBPDS1,TSMMBPDS,TNBPDS12,TNBPDSL3,TNBPDSD,TNBPDSAL'` results are returned as expected.

But if we pass parameter as `'TSMMBPDS,TNBPDS1,TNBPDS12,TNBPDSL3,TNBPDSD,TNBPDSAL'` then no results are returned.

Comment: We can't diagnose your code without actually seeing it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Can you show us how are you calling the function you have created ?

Comment: Seems odd to have a  `)` in this line `'TNBPDS1,TSMMBPDS,TNBPDS12,TNBPDSL3,TNBPDSD,TNBPDSAL' like '%' + ANSR.answer_tag) + '%'` w/o an open `(`  are you user the second '%' is being evaluated?

Comment: You're passing 51 characters (`'TSMMBPDS,TNBPDS1,TNBPDS12,TNBPDSL3,TNBPDSD,TNBPDSAL'`), into a ten character function parameter (`@pAnswerTag varchar(10)`). Also, I think you're assuming that the function is going to do an element-wise comparison of your comma delimited string, and it is not.

Comment: how is the function getting called?  where is the code on how you are calling the function?  Sample data along with expected output would be desirable.

Comment: You might want to read up on table valued parameters. You should be using one here. Also, don't declare a table and insert into. Just use RETURN SELECT....the way you have coded this turns an inline table valued function into a multi-statement table valued function which is often even slower than their scalar function neighbors.